# How to change the colour of the transparency grid in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

My default transparency grid in Photoshop is white.

Where can I change this to transparent or some other color, so that I can more easily differentiate what is really white and what is transparent in my picture?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @[**Farray**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/690/farray) commented:

> `Preferences` → `Transparency & Gamut` is where you change your transparency grid

Comment: I use the following set-up:
http://img807.imageshack.us/i/unbenanntai.png/

I still get a white background. (not in the picture, but as workspace. The alpha value in the pictures is just fine)

but where are the workspace preferences?

Comment: @Alan Ah, I think I misunderstood something. What exactly is the worksheet/workspace you're referring to? Are you talking about the white-gray checkered background or something else?

Comment: yes, exactly. That is white. (I changed it years ago, but I don't remember where :-)

Comment: @Alan  `Preferences -> Transparency & Gamut` is where you change your transparency grid.

Answer (score 0):

I often make a couple of layers and put a full sized dark rectangle in one and a white rectangle in the other and place them behind the layer I'm working on. I can then switch their visibility on and off see see what's there.